# Java int to char output is really strange

Tags: java, char, int

I've got a strange issue with int to char conversion. Here's my code :

```
    char a=100;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(a+1);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println((char)a+1);
    System.out.println((char)101);
    System.out.println( (char)a+1==(char)101 );
```

It gave me this output :

```
d
101

101
e
true
```

which is definitly strange : two differents output seems to be the same when compared ! Why is it so ? And how to make `a+1` beeing seen as a char ?

Thank you for your answer and sorry if there's some english mistakes, it's not my mothertongue.

Answer (score 4):

In this case

```
System.out.println((char)a+1);
```

you are only converting the `a` to a `char` (which it is already). The addition makes the whole expression an `int`, so the overloaded `PrintWriter#println(int)` gets executed. For it to be seen as a `char`, do

```
System.out.println((char) (a+1));
```

[In the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

> The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands
>   of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>
> The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted
>   type of its operands.

and [about promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>     to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>     to long.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

Answer (score 1):

When you use this way:

> (char)a + 1

It firstly converts `a => char`, after this you add  1 of type integer.

And result of calculation is upcasted to integer type.

You can omit this tricky place if you will cast all expression together:

> (char)(a + 1)